# Reading txt-file, change rows to columns, save txt file

Tags: powershell, transpose

I have a txt files (semicolon separated) containing over 3 million records where columns 1 to 4 have some general information. Columns 5 and 6 have detailed information. There can be up to 4 different detailed information for the same general information in columns 1 to 4.

My sample input:

```
Server;Owner;Company;Username;Property;Value
Srv1;Dave;Sandbox;kwus91;Memory;4GB
Srv1;Dave;Sandbox;kwus91;Processes;135
Srv1;Dave;Sandbox;kwus91;Storage;120GB
Srv1;Dave;Sandbox;kwus91;Variant;16
Srv2;Pete;GWZ;aiwq71;Memory;8GB
Srv2;Pete;GWZ;aiwq71;Processes;234
Srv3;Micael;P12;mxuq01;Memory;16GB
Srv3;Micael;P12;mxuq01;Processes;239
Srv3;Micael;P12;mxuq01;Storage;160GB
Srv4;Stefan;MTC;spq61ep;Storage;120GB
```

Desired output:

```
Server;Owner;Company;Username;Memory;Processes;Storage;Variant
Srv1;Dave;Sandbox;kwus91;4GB;135;120GB;16
Srv2;Pete;GWZ;aiwq71;8GB;234;;
Srv3;Micael;P12;mxuq01;16GB;239;160GB;
Srv4;Stefan;MTC;spq61ep;;;120GB;
```

If a values doesn't exist for general information (Columns 1-4) it has to stay blank.

My current code:

```
$a = Import-csv .\Input.txt -Delimiter ";"
$a | FT -AutoSize

$b = @()
foreach ($Server in $a.Server | Select -Unique) {
    $Props = [ordered]@{ Server = $Server }
    $Owner = ($a.where({ $_.Server -eq $Server})).Owner | Select -Unique
    $Company = ($a.where({ $_.Server -eq $Server})).Company | Select -Unique
    $Username = ($a.where({ $_.Server -eq $Server})).Username | Select -Unique

    $Props += @{Owner = $Owner}
    $Props += @{Company = $Company}
    $Props += @{Username = $Username}
    foreach ($Property in $a.Property | Select -Unique){ 
        $Value = ($a.where({ $_.Server -eq $Server -and 
                    $_.Property -eq $Property})).Value

        $Props += @{ $Property = $Value }
    }
    $b += New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property $Props
}
$b | FT -AutoSize
$b | Export-Csv .\Output.txt -NoTypeInformation -Delimiter ";"
```

After a lot of trying and getting errors: My script works.
But it takes a lot of time.
Is there a possibility to make performance better for around 3 Million lines in txt file? I'm calculating with more or less 2.5 Million unique values for `$Server`.

I'm running Windows 7 64bit with PowerShell 4.0.

Comment: SO is not a "I found this code, please make it do what I want" type of place. Please go find a PowerShell tutorial. Get an understanding of what the code actually does. Try to adjust it to your particular needs. Then come back when you have a *specific* question about something in *your* code that you can't get to work.

Comment: Just as a hint I would suggest looking at the help for Import-CSV and figuring out why it does not work with the semi-colons in your file and how you could get it to do that.

Comment: Thank you for reading my question... I wrote "...have troubles with the code. It's only working with comma separated values (CSV and TXT) but not with my semicolon separated files". I first need help to understand how to read that file with a semicolon separator before I can adjust my code... I just wanted to tell the community what I want to do and not that I want you all to do that for me...

Comment: When in doubt, read the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/import-csv?view=powershell-3.0#optional-parameters).

Comment: You're right. Searching for the last hours helped me to get closer to the solution. I updates my Q, tried to explain the code. Now I'm stuck. My current output is the right table with headers and the right values for the "Property" but I don't get objects for "Owner", "Company" or "Username". How can I read out the object in same row as the current server object?

Comment: You may want to look into [`Group-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/group-object?view=powershell-3.0). Group the imported CSV by the common properties (Server, Owner, Company, Username), then build a new object with the additional properties for each group.

Comment: Changed my code. It's working pretty well for a couple of records. But for my file with 3 Million records it's take a long time to get finished :/

Comment: Well, large file is large. It would be possible to speed up processing, but not without a) making some assumptions about the order of the records, and b) doing a lot of things yourself that PowerShell otherwise gives you for free (reading rows, splitting records, grouping, etc.). Also, would you kindly stop messing up the formatting when people already went to the trouble of fixing it for you? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try Something like this:

```
#Import Data and create empty columns
$List=import-csv "C:\temp\file.csv" -Delimiter ";"

#get all properties name with value not empty    
$ListProperty=($List | where Value -ne '' | select property -Unique).Property

#group by server
$Groups=$List | group Server

#loop every rows and store data by group and Property Name
$List | %{

    $Current=$_

    #Take value not empty and group by Property Name
    $Group=($Groups | where Name -eq $Current.Server).Group | where Value -ne '' |  group Property

   #Add all property and first value not empty
    $ListProperty | %{
        $PropertyName=$_
        $PropertyValue=($Group | where Name -eq $PropertyName | select -first 1).Group.Value
        $Current | Add-Member -Name $PropertyName -MemberType NoteProperty -Value $PropertyValue
    }

$Current

} | select * -ExcludeProperty Property, Value -unique  | export-csv "c:\temp\result.csv" -notype -Delimiter ";"
```

Comment: Nice workaround but not useful for me. There is no guarantee that column names for property are always the same.

Comment: I have modifed my code for create dynamically properties ;)

Comment: Thank you, working very well. But it's not transposing my table, right? There is something missing like defining property as value, like in my code the last line in the foreach. Plus getting all other columns in that table afterwards.

Comment: i'm not sure to understand. Have you desired output like in your example? Just export into csv with pipe

Comment: in you exmple you have an error into your sample input: no?

Comment: Add -unique to my code if you rectify your example, its work i think

Comment: Ah forget my comment. I didn't want to add it. I tried again and it worked with output into a textfile. But unfortunately I'm just getting the last row of my input when I try to export `$Current`. Plus there is a first row `#TYPE System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject`

Comment: And dont forget to click on up if you can ;)